# How to test if a react link click is loading the desired component in jest

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I have my react link which is redirecting me to a different component.

```
<Link id="MyTeamLink" to="myTeam">Team</Link>
```

I am trying a test whether the click on the link is redirected to the myTeam Component.
Navbar is my current component, I am finding the link id and simulating the click and updating the wrapper. Now am checking whether the wrapper contains the div id from the myTeam component to test the functionality. But I am getting the length as 0. How do I test this ?

```
  it("home navigates to associateHome page", () => {  
    wrapper = shallow(<Navbar/>).dive();
    wrapper.find("#MyTeamLink").simulate('click');
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('#teamTable').length).toBe(1);   
  });
```

Comment: did you found any answer to this?